# Getting Seconds interval between NSDate, but get always zero seconds

Tags: iphone, cocoa, diff

I want to get diff seconds between NSDate.
I used [NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate] methods, but it returns always zero.
Below is my code.

```
NSLog(@"sent date : %@", message.sentDate);
NSLog(@"prev: %@", _previousShownSentDate);
NSLog(@"%d", [message.sentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_previousShownSentDate]);
```

In here, message.sentDate, _repviousShownSentDate are NSDate object.

But In logs, the difference seconds are always zero.

```
[1363:907] sent date : 2013-05-16 01:36:22 +0000
[1363:907] prev: 2013-05-16 01:36:17 +0000
[1363:907] 0
[1363:907] sent date : 2013-05-16 01:36:25 +0000
[1363:907] prev: 2013-05-16 01:36:17 +0000
[1363:907] 0
```

The third log line must be 5 (01:36:22 and 01:36:17). but it is zero.

I don't understand what i do mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "`%d`" is an integer and the value returned by "`timeIntervalSinceDate:`" is a double (NSTimeInterval).

Use "`%4.2f`" in that third "`NSLog`" line.